# IBM Liberty's viewSettings command keeps saying "The password for this proxy is not encoded"

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty, websphere-8

I have an IBM WebSphere (v8) Application Server Liberty v16.0.0.4 installed on Windows located in the following directory: `C:\Program Files\IBM\WAS85511LP`. I am trying to install some features using the command `installUtility install servlet-4.0`, run from the \bin\ directory. However, I'm getting a message saying "The credentials for the configured proxy server cannot be authenticated".

I am behind a corporate proxy, so I have configured a file at `\etc\repositories.properties` with the following contents:

```
proxyHost=myproxyhost
proxyPort=8080
proxyUser=myproxyuser
proxyPassword={xor}EncodedPassword
```

I have made sure multiple times these are the correct values for our proxy, and when using `installUtility viewSettings` I can see Liberty is detecting the changes and correctly reading the file. However, I keep getting the message "The password for this proxy is not encoded".

I have used the `securityUtility encode [mypassword]` as indicated by Liberty itself, but it still thinks it's not encoded. I have made sure there are absolutely no weird characters or blank spaces or file encoding errors by using different text editors and by decoding the password using [this website](https://strelitzia.net/wasXORdecoder/wasXORdecoder.html). I have tried using AES encoding and HASH encoding by adding `--encoding=aes` and `--encoding=hash` to no avail. I have tried using single quotes and double quotes and no quotes around the password unsuccessfully. I have tried testing a dummy password with only ASCII characters like `hello` and Liberty's `viewSettings` tool still tells me it's not encoded!

There's no other option but to use this specific version of WAS Liberty because of corporate software packages and blocking all external downloads. I've only found two other questions about this on SO and they were all solved using single quotes on passwords with special characters in them. Well, mine isn't, and I've run out of ideas.

(Yes, I have read IBM's documentation and explained ChatGPT 4 my problem in detail. Neither helped.)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're able to get to the repository, note that WebSphere Liberty 16.0.0.4 does not support servlet-4.0.  Support for servlet-4.0 was introduced in 18.0.0.2.

16.0.0.4 was released in 2016 and is well out of support, which means you'll be unable to receive any fixes, including for any security vulnerabilities. I would strongly advise advocating for updating your companies corporate software packages, not only so that you can use newer features like servlet-4.0 (which itself is quite old at this point), but also to be able to receive support and security fixes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up, but many things have been tried by tech leads to update software packages and management just does not care. We do have the ability to use Open Liberty though, and that one doesn't throw the encoding error. It's honestly pretty shitty to deal with stupid company policies but we programmers are not first class citizens in my field, so it is what it is I guess.